# javascript алгоритмы и структуры данных

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста,очень часто в вакансиях и стажировках по javascript пишут,что нужно знание алгоритмов и структур данных.Где лучше их изучить и насколько глубоко их нужно знать?Сорри,если глупые вопросы задаю..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритмы и структуры данных не связаны с конкретным языком программирования.

Это, так сказать, общие теоретические знания.

Изучить можно много где. Классика: это книги Дональда Кнута.

Можно еще почитать книги Роберта Седжвика. У него так же есть курс на Coursera.

Ну или просто почитать в инете про такие вещи как список, стек, очереди, хеш и дальше по ссылкам в википедии :)